# Wifi & touchpad don't work in live USB - will they work after install? (Samsung NP900X5L)

Tags: wireless, touchpad, live-usb, laptop, samsung

I just booted from a live USB image of Ubuntu 14.04 desktop (64bit) on my Samsung laptop and found that the touchpad doesn't work and the wifi device isn't detected (ethernet works fine though).

Will the installer install drivers that aren't loaded by the live environment?  Or does their not working here mean that they definitely won't work once installed onto the harddrive either?

Comment: Is is 14.04 or 14.04.4?

Comment: Hi, it is 14.04.

Comment: Try 14.04.4. It has better hardware support. 14.04 has a very old kernel.

Comment: Wifi should work after you install drivers, but the touchpad depend on kernel support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is not supported and it will not work after the install for that version so I recommend that you install Ubuntu 15.10 or the daily build of 16.04 and it will be working correctly.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: What wireless device does he have that you *know* is supported in 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead with the installation and neither worked, but after upgrading to the latest stable kernel both now work fine.